# ArgumentError in MembersController#login invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was trying to set up twitter login system with omuniauth gem and suddenly it happened. I can't show any page and have the error message below.
"ArgumentError in MembersController#login invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII" Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

And this is the logs in terminal command.

☆terminal command log①

```
 ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII):
      better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/error_page.rb:82:in `exception_message'
      (erubis:734:in `render'
      erubis (2.7.0) lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:65:in `eval'
      erubis (2.7.0) lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:65:in `result'
      better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/error_page.rb:25:in `render'
      better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:96:in `show_error_page'
      better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:88:in `rescue in protected_app_call'
      better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
      better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
      better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
      railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
      railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
      activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
      railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
      activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
      railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
      railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
      railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
      /Users/aramakikuniharu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-   p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
      /Users/aramaki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
      /Users/aramaki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

☆terminal command log ②

```
   SyntaxError -     
    /Users/aramaki/railsprojects/miniSNS/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:30: 
     invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
    /Users/aramaki/railsprojects/miniSNS/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
  end　　　　　
      ^:
```

☆application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery


  def logout 
   session[:user_id] = nil
   redirect_to "members/login"
   return
 end

  def login?
     if session[:user_id] != nil then
        return true
     else
        return false
     end
  end

  def me? obj = nil
     id_num = obj !=nil ? obj.member_id : params[:id].to_i
     if session[:user_id] == id_num then
        return true
     else
        return false
     end
  end

  def admin?
    Member.find(session[:user_id]).admin
  end　　　　　
　　　　　  
  def checklogin?　　
    if session[:user_id] != nil then
        return true
    else　　　　　
        redirect_to '/members/login'
        return false
    end
  end

  def checkme? obj = nil
    id_num = obj !=nil ? obj.member_id : params[:id].to_i
    if session[:user_id] == id_num then
        return true
    else
        redirect_to '/members/' + session[:user_id].to_s
        return false
    end
  end

  def checkadmin?
    if Member.find(session[:user_id]).admin then
       return true
    else
      redirect_to '/members/' + session[:user_id].to_s
      return false
    end
  end

    helper_method :current_user

  private
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= Member.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

end
```

Comment: try add this at the beginning of the controller (exactly the first line of the file) `# encoding: utf-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code in a hex editor shows, that you have a bunch of invisible characters at some points in the code. This happens to me some time when hitting `Alt`+`Space`

[image: See image]

If you haven't declared that your [ruby source file is UTF-8](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Encoding#Using_Encodings) Ruby **1.9** tries to treat the file as US-ASCII and cannot parse those (They changed this in Ruby 2.0.0 to UTF-8). You should remove all those characters (for example there are 5 invisible characters that are not all spaces after the `end`on line 30), then it should work fine.